# При создании проекта Laravel выскакивает ошибка Failed to execute unzip -qq. Как результат [RuntimeException] Could not scan for classes inside

Tags: php, laravel, composer, php7, php7.2

Пытаюсь создать проект с помощью `laravel new projectname`  или `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectname`. В процессе создания проекта выскакивают ошибки такого рода:

```
Failed to execute unzip -qq  '/home/user/laravel- 
dev/blogr/vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest- 
php/58f0e32d1c5452719a54dac2041afbcd' -d '/home/user/laravel-    dev/blogr/vendor/composer/1489d62e'

[/home/user/laravel-dev/blogr/vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/58f0e32d1c5452719a54dac2041afbcd]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/user/laravel-dev/blogr/vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/58f0e32d1c5452719a54dac2041afbcd or
    /home/user/laravel-dev/blogr/vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/58f0e32d1c5452719a54dac2041afbcd.zip, and cannot find /home/user/laravel-dev/blogr/vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/58f0e32d1c5452719a54dac2041afbcd.ZIP, period.
```

**Как результат**

```
                                                                               
  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Could not scan for classes inside "/home/user/laravel-dev/blogr/vendor/phpu  
  nit/php-token-stream/src/" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

Полный консольный вывод выглядит следующим образом: 
[Консольный вывод](https://dojustnow.github.io/LaravelError/)

Пытался использовать разные версии php(7.0-7.2), устанавливал пакеты zip, unzip, php-zip.

Не могу решить данную проблему.

Comment: composer clearcache попробуйте

Comment: Благодарю composer clearcache помог.